# Delete trailing newline in Atom for existing files

Tags: regex, newline, atom-editor

I have about 150 files that have an additional newline at the end which needs to be removed. I have set the 'Ensure trailing space' setting from the whitespace package in Atom, however it only works for new files. I need to apply it to existing files, since I cannot edit each file to delete the last line.
I have tried using a regex, but Atom selects all line breaks instead of just the last. `\z` doesn't seem to work, it simply selects all `z` characters.

Is there a regex that will help me select the very last newline in Atom? Or is there a way to apply the settings to existing files?

Comment: Try `\n$(?![\s\S])`

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew. It says no results found!

Comment: Is that because of `\n`? Try a more versatile `(?:\r\n?|\n)(?![\s\S])`

Comment: Perfect! Works. Please add this as an answer, I will accept it. Furthermore, I need another regex help, I will add another question, please can you take a look at it?

Comment: Please let know what it is about.

Comment: Added a question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56323075/regex-to-check-number-of-spaces-after-full-stop-strictly-2-required

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
(?:\r\n?|\n)(?![\s\S])
```

**Details**

- `(?:\r\n?|\n)` - a CRLF, CR or LF line break
- `(?![\s\S])` - not followed with any char.

[Regex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=(%3F%3A%5Cr%5Cn%3F%7C%5Cn)(%3F!%5B%5Cs%5CS%5D)):

[image]