# Regex to check number of spaces after full stop - Strictly 2 required

Tags: regex, atom-editor

I need to check occurrences where I have put one whitespace after a full-stop, and replace it by 2 spaces. I have the Regex for it, but Atom seems to call in invalid.

`(?<=\.|\") {1,}(?=[a-zA-Z])`

Conditions:

1. 1 spaces after period.
2. If period in with a closing double quote, then 1 space after the quote.

The above regex works perfectly for my conditions however Atom is not able to validate it. I need to use it for existing files.

Comment: What are you trying to do here? Remove/replace what with? Could you please provide an example text with expected result?

Comment: If you need to replace with a single space, try `([."]) {2,}(?=[a-zA-Z])` and replace with `"$1 "` (with no quotation marks)

Comment: Hey, I am trying to check if my text matches the above conditions. And if there is any place that I have missed to put 2 spaces. So I think ideally I should be checking for 1 space after the fullstop.

Comment: I have improved the question.

Comment: Then even `([."]) ([a-zA-Z])` to replace with `$1  $2` (two spaces between `$1` and `$2`) should work. See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nb5OV6/1).

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/nb5OV6/1

Comment: Yes it working, however I will need to manually check for `period` in places like `mr.`, or within the quotes. But that is alright, I can take care of that. Thanks a a lot again, please add this as an answer, I will accept it. :)

Comment: I can improve the answer if you provide some sample text with expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
([."]) ([a-zA-Z])
```

and replace with `$1  $2`. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nb5OV6/1) and a [regex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=(%5B.%22%5D)%20(%5Ba-zA-Z%5D)):

[image]

**Details**

- `([."])` - Group 1 (its value is referred to with `$1` backreference from the replacement pattern): `.` or `"`
- - a space (use `\s` to match any whitespace)
- `([a-zA-Z])` - Group 2 (`$2`): an ASCII letter.

Comment: Thanks man! Please can you make it in such a way that it selects only full-stops? As in `sentence ends. ` or `sentence ends." ` Notice the space after full-stop, and in the second case if is after the closing quote. Right now it is selecting even the quotes which do not end with a full-stop. The rule to follow is 1 space after a period, and if the period comes inside the closing quote, then the space after the closing quote.

Comment: I will accept the answer anyway, since it is working for me.

Comment: @RutwickGangurde I guess you want `(\.") ([a-zA-Z])`

Comment: Perfect. I removed the `"` from the first one, so it searches for period and space. Right?

Comment: @RutwickGangurde If it works as intended, yes :) If you need to search `<period><space><letter>`, use `(\.) ([a-zA-Z])`